# Set operations in swift

Tags: swift

```
let a: Set = [1, 2, 3]
let b: Set = [3, 5, 2]
if ! a.____b) {
   let c:____= a.____(b)
}
```

Drag and drop from the options below to create a new set "c", with only the values common to both "a" and "b", if not all of the values of set "a" are contained in set "b".

**intersection**, **union**, **subtracting**, **isSubset(of:**, **isSuperset(of:**, **Set**.

I'm just starting out and is confused about this particular code section. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Seems you have lost many important parts of your code while posting. Please fix it.

Comment: Filling the "holes“ is probably part of the exercise.

Comment: @MartinR, seems you are right. Though I wonder if this sort of exercise is useful for learning programming...

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to explain this better. It sounds like a coding exercise where you've been given part of the code and you're supposed to fill in some blanks.. If so, can you edit your question to explain that and and put underscores in the blanks you are supposed to fill in. I'm guessing it's `if !a.__b) {` and `let c: Set = a.__(b)` but you should tell us.

Comment: Have you learned [Set operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations) from Math class? It is not something special to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Dee. I'm just learning Swift myself also.
Another way of saying "common to both a and b" would be "the intersection of a and b", and another way of saying "if not all of the values of set a are contained in set b" would be "if set a is not a subset of set b".

```
let a: Set = [1, 2, 3]
let b: Set = [3, 5, 2]
if !a.isSubset(of: b) {
    let c: Set = a.intersection(b)
}
```